# sql isnull update with laravel eloquent update

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, isnull

current table (TARGET)

```
field1   field2   field3    field4
apple1   apple2   apple3   apple4
```

The data I want to add (SOURCE)

```
SourceData = ("orange1","orange2",null,"orange4")
```

The result I expected after updating

```
field1      field2   field3   field4
orange1   orange2   apple3   orange4
```

I can do this with sql query, I just want to do it with laravel eloquent.

Anyone suggestion ? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have find the model you want:
eg: `$model = App\Target::where('field1', 'orange1');`

You can use the [update](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates) function:

```
App\Target::find(id)->update([
  'field1' => 'orange1',
  'field2' => 'orange2',
  'field4' => 'orange4'
]);
```

The `update` function updates only the specified fields.

If you want to update all rows, then the following does the trick:

```
App\Target::update([
  'field1' => 'orange1',
  'field2' => 'orange2',
  'field4' => 'orange4'
]);
```